# Migrating Mongo within VPN to Azure cosmos fails

Tags: azure, migration, mongodb

I'm working on migrating my Mongo database to Azure Cosmos. I'm using the `MigrationMongoService Azure Database Migration Service` but when I create a project, it fails because of connectivity problems.

I think the problem might be due to me having that Mongo in another machine for which you need access via VPN.

So maybe Azure doesn't have that access although I'm connected to that VPN in my local?

How can I create a link between my VPN and the one that I'm using on Azure? Just letting Azure read on my VPN would do the trick as well.